# Routing to a New Route While Accessing Same Data Source

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, angular2-routing

I understand how routing and passing information between components generally works in Angular 2. For instance, you would use the following kind of setup to load a component and an accompanying specific id:

```
<a *ngFor="let product of products"
  [routerLink]="['/product-details', product.id]">
  {{ product.name }}
</a>
```

But let's say you're already on a route, and now you want to click a link to load a new route (with narrower information details), but all the data you're accessing is in the same product.id source as the one you just clicked away from (because they draw from the same api end-point and product.id in your api (mongoDB)). How would you go about doing that?

In this case you can't just pass in the "product.id" because you're wanting to access an array WITHIN the same product.id as the previous route/component. So you want a new route, but info from the same data source (same product.id). To clarify, the new route has "contact" for the component, and then "contact.id" for the specific parameter. But, it's not a separate data source, because "contact.id" is an array value WITHIN the product.id I just clicked away from. How would you do this?

Presently I've got a new route opening up, that lists "contact" and then the specific contact id - so the route looks like: http://localhost:4200/contact/21469568eds3913283df5cs. So that's working as expected. Just a reminder, the contact id listed here is within an array of my product.id - it's not a different data source. So how do I access information from the previous route's id in the new route? Because - again - same data source, just new route. Right now I'm getting "undefined" errors in the new component/route.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a design issue. If you have a route to a `product` you work with, and then open a `contact` which is assigned to that particular `product` (as you say contacts are an array within your product) , then you should reflect that in your route, too. For instance

```
/product/:productId/contact/:contactId
```

That way you have all relevant context information in your route. In this case a [Resolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html) makes perfect sense for all routes that fit the pattern

```
/product/:productId/**
```

That way you'll have easy access to the product, even if you have activated a route to the details of a contact. Caching the product within the `ProductResolver` might make sense if you expect multiple routes called for the same productId (and the product is expensive to get, e.g. due to complex SQL joins, or will change very infrequently)

Comment: To clarify, my routes aren't nested like this. Rather I want to go from 'product/productId' to 'contact/contactId' -- but the data for the second route is drawn from the same data source (same document) as the first component. Is a resolver still a good option here?

Comment: Oh, right. I've adjusted my answer according to your info.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Matt. I will definitely look into this. So, large picture view, are resolvers designed for this specific kind of situation? And would you see this as THE recommended way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish, or one of several ways? Just looking for a little more context re: situations where a new route is getting info from the same source set as a previous route.

Comment: And one last question - in my situation are you saying I would HAVE TO make my route look like this: "/product/:productId/contact/:contactId"? Or can I use something just  like "/contact/contactId"? Just wanting to know so I can explain to my team. :)

Comment: Starting with the recent question: No, you are not bound to make it look like this. Question is, could I copy the ``/contact/contactId`` in a new browser tab and it would show me the same information even without knowing about the product it is contained in? If so, i.e. the contact is a strong entityt and its contactId is unique throughout all of your products, then the route above makes sense.

Comment: ...and regarding your first question, this is not the typical use case for resolvers. It is the added caching feature that would give you access to the same data even when changing routes without the need to load them from the backend every time in your particular use case.